# VAR or VECM model- 4 variables

Tags: r, time-series

I have a model consisting 4 variables, two of which are stationary at level and two that are I1 stationary. There seems to be a cointegration relationship between the two I1 variables after running the Johansen test.

Do I use a VAR model but taking the first differences of these I1 variables and ignore cointegration, or I proceed with a VECM model? If is the latter how do I proceed?

Comment: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/148994/var-or-vecm-for-a-mix-of-stationary-and-nonstationary-variables Does this not answer your question?

Comment: @MattP do you know how can i construct such a model in R? Do I need to create the VECM with the two cointegrated  variables and then use the error correction term  somehow in the VAR model containing all 4 parameters? How do I do this in practice?

Comment: I would appreciate some help on these in terms of R code, if anybody can help me it would be great!! Thanks in advance