# Can second order differences stationary series be estimated via VECM model without considering support from economic theory?

Tags: time-series, stationarity, vector-error-correction-model, differencing

Because some series contain negative raw data, and data is normalized by MinMax.
Can VECM be used after second-order difference where the series are stationary? If can, whether the number of lagged difference is the p-1 or p-2 through VAR(p)?

From Comments:

integrated of order two (Δ2) for all series. My data is not only integrated of order one, but must two to keep all series stationary. According to  Lutkepohl "New Introduction to Multiple Time Series Analysis", it only gives proof of integrated of order one, but no proof more than one. When I get through the chapter, it seems that Δd Xt works. Because so far I am not writing paper but just the aim to conduct a robust model without residual autocorrelation and not-bad generalized model. To some degree, the model need not be so strict with theory or mathematic proof.

Comment: Could you describe what you are doing in a bit more detail, e.g. using symbols such as $\Delta^2 x_t$ for the second difference of $x_t$? What the variables are, what their orders of integration are, what transformations of the variables are included directly into the model.

Comment: integrated of order two (Δ2) for all series. My data is not only integrated of order one, but must two to keep all series stationary. According to  Lutkepohl "New Introduction to Multiple Time Series Analysis", it only gives proof of integrated of order one, but no proof more than one. When I get through the chapter, it seems that Δd Xt works. Because so far I am not writing paper but just the aim to conduct a stable model without residual autocorrelation and not-bad generalized model. To some degree, the model need not be so strict with theory or mathematic proof.

Comment: The transformations of the variables is normalized by MinMax, whose range is between 0 and 1.

Comment: Are all of your time series I(2), or are some of them I(1) or I(0)?

Comment: Some of them I(1)，some have to  I(2) to make them stationary.

Comment: Could you please write this down in detail? E.g. say: I have $x_1$ which is I(2) according to the ADF test or whatever other way you used to determined the order of integration; $x_2$ which is I(1) according to ...; $x_3$ which is I(0) according to ...; and so on. Just to make it absolutely clear what you have. Then it will be easier to take it from there.

Comment: 1  which is I(1) according to the ADF test,
2  which is I(2) according to the ADF test,
x3 which is I(1) according to the ADF test,
In order to let all three to be stationary, I finally conduct all Xs , which are  I(2) according to the ADF test. Then determine p from VAR and use it to build VECM model.

Comment: I have posted answers to perhaps half a dozen related threads. One of them is [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/148994/var-or-vecm-for-a-mix-of-stationary-and-nonstationary-variables). Some more are [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=I%281%29+I%280%29+var); you may wish to narrow the search down by adding additional keywords.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you have $x_1$ and $x_3$ being I(1) and $x_2$ being I(2). This is what I would do.

1. Take the first difference of $x_2$ to make it I(1) and call that $y$: $y:=\Delta x_2$.
2. Inspect whether $(x_1,y,x_3)$ are cointegrated.
3. If they are cointegrated, use a VEC model for them. Select the lag order as you would if $(x_1,y,x_3)$ were raw data.
   If they are not cointegrated, inspect whether any pair is cointegrated.
   ___ If no pairs are cointegrated, use a VAR on $(\Delta x_1,\Delta y,\Delta x_3)$.
   ___ If one pair is cointegrated, without loss of generality say it is $(x_1,x_3)$. Use a restricted VEC for $(x_1,y,x_3)$ where $y$ is absent from the cointegrating relationship. For details, see ["VAR or VECM for a mix of stationary and nonstationary variables?"](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/148994/var-or-vecm-for-a-mix-of-stationary-and-nonstationary-variables).
   ___ If two pairs are cointegrated, then the triple must be cointegrated, which contradicts the previous step.

Instead of 2. and 3. you could also just use a VAR on $(x_1,y,x_3)$, as this turns out to be a rather good option regardless of cointegration, according to Ashley & Verbrugge ["To difference or not to difference: a Monte Carlo investigation of inference in vector autoregression models"](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Randal-Verbrugge-2/publication/46515470_To_difference_or_not_to_difference_a_Monte_Carlo_investigation_of_inference_in_vector_autoregression_models/links/00b7d51695f16a2d95000000/To-difference-or-not-to-difference-a-Monte-Carlo-investigation-of-inference-in-vector-autoregression-models.pdf) (2009).

What I would **not** do is difference each series twice and try to fit a VECM. First, two of the series will be overdifferenced and as such will contain unit-root moving average components. Second, VECM will not be appropriate as there can be no cointegration between variables that, after the differencing, are at most I(0).

Comment: I have posted answers to perhaps half a dozen related threads. One of them is [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/148994/var-or-vecm-for-a-mix-of-stationary-and-nonstationary-variables). Some more are [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=I%281%29+I%280%29+var); you may wish to narrow the search down by adding additional keywords.